# Erro ao realizar uma criação de tabela SQLITE

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, android-fragment, sqlite-studio

Estou tento o seguinte erro:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: np (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, nome, email, np, tipoFunc FROM usuarios ORDER BY nome ASC
                                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
                                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1165)
                                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1036)
                                                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1204)
                                                                                                   at com.example.gerdaumanagement.gerdaumanagement.db_funcao.buscar(db_funcao.java:61)
                                                                                                   at com.example.gerdaumanagement.gerdaumanagement.usuario.onCreateView(usuario.java:40)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

E código de criação da tabela é:

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("create table usuarios(_id integer primary key autoincrement, nome text not null, email text not null, np integer not null, tipoFunc text not null);");
}
```

E aqui eu estou executando uma função de buscar os dados inseridos na tabela.

```
public List<usuarioData> buscar(){
    List<usuarioData> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] colunas = new String[]{"_id","nome","email!","np","tipoFunc"};

    Cursor cursor = db.query("usuarios", colunas, null, null, null, null, "nome ASC");

    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        do{

            usuarioData u = new usuarioData();

            u.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            u.setNome(cursor.getString(1));
            u.setEmail(cursor.getString(2));
            u.setNp(cursor.getString(3));
            u.setTipoFunc(cursor.getString(4));


            list.add(u);

        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return(list);
}
```

Alguém sabe como resolver esse erro?

Comment: Vc já tentou desinstalar e instalar novamente o app ou mudar a versão do banco? Qdo vc adiciona uma nova coluna no banco, é necessário

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO @LeonardoDias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que deve ser porque você incluiu um "!" no nome da coluna nessa linha:

```
String[] colunas = new String[]{"_id","nome","email!","np","tipoFunc"};
```

Como você está buscando os dados de todas as colunas, essa linha nem é necessária. Pode chamar a query direto dessa forma:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("usuarios", null, null, null, null, null, "nome ASC");
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado. Então essa String colunas eu usaria apenas se eu quisesse ver algumas colunas e não todas?

Comment: Isso. Pra não precisar trazer dados da base desnecessariamente, se você não vai usar.